# Number of samples and instances in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to determine the ideal number of samples and instances of data that I should collect. Basically, I have to create a dataset of network traffic.

I'm not sure how the number of samples and instances in each sample influences the training data. Is it a large number of samples good? Then, should I try to collect as many instances as possible?

My idea was to collect two different samples in different days. Then for each program/protocol in each samples I would collect around 30 instances.

And I will be using the SVM algorithm.

Thanks for your help, and any clarification. And, I'm also not sure if I'm confusing definitions (samples vs instances).

Comment: What is it exactly that your are trying to learn? Is this a supervised learning problem where you have classes/labels for each instance? If so, will the class be the website? Why are you collecting samples over different days?

Comment: What I'm trying to learn is how the traffic changes. For example if the traffic produced by a program with a specific input now is going to be the same as the traffic produced by the same program with the same input tomorrow. It will be supervised learning because I will tell the classifier which traffic instances belong to each classes/labels. Yes, the class will be the program (e.g. website, protocol). I'm collecting samples over different days to try to have a large variety of possible changes in the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about the distinction that you are making between instances and samples (usually they mean the same thing), but in general (so long as your data collection process is sound) the more data the better. There are some results on the number of data instances required to make some probabilistic guarantees on the performance of most learners but these are usually not practical and will overshoot how much data you need. So overall, collect as much data as feasible both in terms of collection cost and then in terms of computation cost for running your learning algorithms.

Comment: You are right, I was making a wrong distinction between instances and samples, they are all the same. Should I be concerned with a possible  overfitting? How can I calculate the cost of running the learning algorithm for a given number of instances? And after I collect the data can I kind a adjust/fit the number of instances for my algorithm? Like trying different number of instances until finding an optimal number or something ?

Comment: Over fitting will come from having too few instances/ too complicated a model (e.g. having a lot of coefficients in linear regression). As far as to the cost of algorithms, you could look up the big O of them, but for the most part just running them should suffice. But, you shouldn't really view the number of instances as a tuning parameter. Barring outliers, the more the data you have the better. You should however, cross validate other parameters (e.g.the bandwidth on the Gaussian Kernel) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply. I will be collecting the maximum amount of data that I can. I need to read all those concepts you have mentioned to fully understand the problems.